# How to style the transform anchors on a Konva element?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

How do I style the transform anchors (e.g., blue boxes) on a transformable Konva element? Note I'm using Konva with `konva-react`.

[image: Transformable Konva element]

**Example 1:**
In other words, what if I wanted to make the boxes grey, and semi-transparent? Or change the size?

[image: Sample of ideal styled transformable element]

**Example 2:**
Or, what if I waned to remove the anchors and make the entire edge of a `Rect` able to be grabbed to resize? In other words, make the anchor transparent and full-height/full-width.

Answer (score 0):

I’d start your research using the elements from this example:

https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Image_Resize.html

It shows that the transformer has various bits you can style in your own way. Good luck with that.